# Efficient way to check if a traversable has more than 1 element in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I need to check if a `Traversable` (which I already know to be `nonEmpty`) has a single element or more.

I could use `size`, but (tell me if I'm wrong) I suspect that this could be O(n), and traverse the collection to compute it.

I could check if `tail.nonEmpty`, or if `.head != .last`

Which are the pros and cons of the two approaches? Is there a better way? (for example, will `.last` do a full iteration as well?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All approaches that cut elements from beginning of the collection and return tail are inefficient. For example `tail` for `List` is O(1), while `tail` for `Array` is O(N). Same with `drop`.

I propose using `take`:

```
 list.take(2).size == 1 // list is singleton
```

`take` is declared to return whole collection if collection length is less that `take`'s argument. Thus there will be no error if collection is empty or has only one element. On the other hand if collection is huge `take` will run in O(1) time nevertheless. Internally `take` will start iterating your collection, take two steps and break, putting elements in new collection to return.

**UPD:** I changed condition to exactly match the question

Comment: You can avoid building any collection with `view(0,2).size`.

Answer (score 3):

Not all will be the same, but let's take a worst case scenario where it's a `List`. `last` will consume the entire `List` just to access that element, as will `size`.

`tail.nonEmpty` is obtained from a `head :: tail` pattern match, which doesn't need to consume the entire `List`. If you already know the list to be non-empty, this should be the obvious choice.

But not all `tail` operations take constant time like a `List`: [Scala Collections Performance](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can take a view of a traversable.  You can slice the `TraversableView` lazily.

The initial star is because the REPL prints some output.

```
scala> val t: Traversable[Int] = Stream continually { println("*"); 42 }
*
t: Traversable[Int] = Stream(42, ?)

scala> t.view.slice(0,2).size
*
res1: Int = 2

scala> val t: Traversable[Int] = Stream.fill(1) { println("*"); 42 }
*
t: Traversable[Int] = Stream(42, ?)

scala> t.view.slice(0,2).size
res2: Int = 1
```

The advantage is that there is no intermediate collection.

```
scala> val t: Traversable[_] = Map((1 to 10) map ((_, "x")): _*)
t: Traversable[_] = Map(5 -> x, 10 -> x, 1 -> x, 6 -> x, 9 -> x, 2 -> x, 7 -> x, 3 -> x, 8 -> x, 4 -> x)

scala> t.take(2)
res3: Traversable[Any] = Map(5 -> x, 10 -> x)
```

That returns an unoptimized Map, for instance:

```
scala> res3.getClass
res4: Class[_ <: Traversable[Any]] = class scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap

scala> Map(1->"x",2->"x").getClass
res5: Class[_ <: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String]] = class scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map2
```

Answer (score 0):

What about pattern matching?

```
 itrbl match { case _::Nil => "one"; case _=>"more" }
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as using .tail.nonEmpty? Sure, you could argue it's more elegant...

Comment: Actually, I think it should be more like calling head twice which translates to itetable.iterator.next while tail.isEmpty looks like iterator.next iterator.hasNext